# How to check if my Ubuntu has any malware or viruses?

Tags: ubuntu, antivirus, malware

I found that someone tried to change my Gmail password several times. I was wondering if my Ubuntu 18.04 is infected by a virus or some other malware. Is there any tool that I can use to check if my computer is secure enough? I am a beginner Ubuntu user.

Comment: Not an expert, but I think ClamAV is popular. https://www.clamav.net

Comment: A much more common attack vector is if you use the same password on multiple sites.